# Prove arctan metric is equivalent to euclidean metric

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, trigonometry, metric-spaces, equivalent-metrics

Given two metrics in $\mathbb{R}$, $d_1(x,y)=|\arctan x-\arctan y|$, and $d_2(x,y)=|x-y|$.

I need to prove those two metrics are equivalent. I have the definition that two metrics are said to be equivalent if they generate the same open sets.

I suppose that I have to show double inclusion of two open balls: $B_{d1}(x,r_1)\subset B_d2(x,r_2)$ and $B_{d2}(x,r_2)\subset B_{d1}(x, r_1)$ to get $B_{d1}(x,r_1)=B_{d2}(x,r_2)$

Here is my attempt after read GReyes's comment.

let $a\in\mathbb{R}$ and $r>0$, we have a $d_2$-open ball $B_{d1}(a,r)$. $\forall b\in B_{d2}$, $d_2(a,b)<r$. By Mean Value Theorem, we have $|\arctan a-\arctan b|\leq|f^{'}(x)||a-y|$ where $f^{'}x=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$. Hence we have $|\arctan a-\arctan b|\leq|a-b|<r$. So we can find an open-ball $B_{d1}(a,r^{'})$ such that $r^{'}\leq r$ and $B_{d1}(a,r^{'})\subset B_{d2}(a,r)$.

Comment: Observe that $|\arctan x-\arctan y|\le |x-y|$.

Comment: Also, generating the same topology does not mean that the balls are same. It means that inside any ball of positive radius w.r.t. the first metric there is a ball with positive radius w.r.t. the second metric and vice versa.

Comment: They are not equivalent. $d_1$ is not a complete metric.

Comment: @GReyes I think I get the inequality part by Mean Value Theorem, but I am not sure if what I did is what you suggested in the comment. Also, could you please give me a hint of how to prove the other direction?

Comment: @Ningxin Sorry if I misused any terms here since I am kind of new to metric space. But I do not see a restriction on complete metric in the definition I got. Could you please elaborate your statement?

Comment: @AnalysisRookie The thing is, your definition of equivalence of metrics is nonstandard. The commonly adopted definition is: Two metrics $d_1$ and $d_2$ are equivalent iff there exist positive numbers $c_1$ and $c_2$ such that for all $x$ and $y$, $d_2(x,y)\leq c_1d_1(x,y)$ and $d_1(x,y)\leq c_2d_2(x,y)$. In this definition, equivalent metrics do induce the same topology, but two metrics inducing the same topology need not be equivalent.

Comment: The ideas behind your $\arctan$ metric is as follows: $\arctan$ is a homeomorphism (a continuous bijection with a continuous inverse) from $\mathbb{R}$ onto $I=(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$. The open subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ can be identified with the open subsets of $I$ through $\arctan$. So what your $\arctan$ metric does is, taking all points in $\mathbb{R}$ to an topologically equivalent space $I$, and measure their distances there.

Comment: @Ningxin Is the commonly adopted definition consistent with the strong equivalence in [Equivalence of metrics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_metrics)? I feel the one I got from class is similar to the topological equivalence definition.

Comment: @Ningxin Your are wrong. OP's definition is the standard definition.

Comment: @geetha290krm Can you provide some source that says so? What I said above is the impression I gained from math people around me. It makes a lot of sense to me, because equivalence of metrics sounds like it should really be a property of metrics, not topologies. I'm happy with the terminologies "topological equivalence" and "strong equivalence", though.

Comment: @AnalysisRookie Yes, what I defined is the same as the strong equivalence.

Comment: @NingxinmTwo metric/two norms are equivalent if they induice the same topology. It so happens that in the case of norms you get those inequalities, but for metrics you don't. Ref. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_metrics

Comment: @Ningxin typically in metric space analysis we would call your definition a bi-Lipschitz equivalence, since the identity map becomes bi-Lipschitz.  As for OP's definition of equivalent metrics I think its pretty standard but I don't want to swear its universal, and its one of those cases where it probably doesn't hurt to specify you're talking topologically.